# Jquery loading image - handling the Back / Forward button in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loading

I used following method to show loading image while loading a page to inform the user the loading action is in progress. If I press Back button in the web browser, sometimes the page starts with loading image and the page is stucked. I want to ensure that if the user presses the back / forward button in web browser, the loading image want be displayed.

The method in use.

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
  //This line below would hide the div when the page load by default
  $('#loading').hide();

  //This would display when the user clicks the button
  $('#buttonID').click(function (){
    if( $('#search_string').val().length !== 0 ) {    
    $('#loading').show();
    }
  });
   $('a.la').click(function (){
    $('#loading').show();
 });
});
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loading').hide();
});
</script>
```

Css

```
#loading {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;

   z-index: 99;
   text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id='buttonID' type="submit"></button>
<a class="la" href="search.php">Some text</a><br>
```

Comment: You can try adding `<script> $('#loading').hide();</script>` to just before the `</body>` instead of in the document.ready

Comment: It seems to work. I will test it while working with the pages. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to listen to the browser and write your application in that way so these things become irrelevant.

And it's also true that browsers are locking more and more things to client javascript apps so it's highly likely your app is going to fail after (few) browser upgrades

This is well explained here:  [HTML 5 History Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history)
And Demonstrated Here :  [History Demo](http://html5demos.com/history)